# Setting Response Headers of HTTPServeletResponse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, http-headers

So, I am constructing a URL from values from a database. Now, I want to make sure that the response headers are what I specify for this URL. How do I achieve this?

For instance, if I construct a URL such as `www.google.com/username=ak&password=bk`, I want to make sure that the connection is keep alive for the response that you get when you hit the URL. How do I do this within JSP/Java?

The reason being, I'm trying to render a video on an `iOS` device from my `CMS` however this doesn't work and from what I have read, the response headers must be set. How do I set response headers for a URL that I might hit?

The following method is how I am setting the response however the response is not the url I make. The URL I make is something like `www.uisghsfgsgsfg.com/cs/sksjdgs/appl`. I am confused as to what the response means in the context of this page.

```
class URLConstructor extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
   response.setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
   ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream =
       new ByteArrayOutputStream(512);
   response.setContentLength(byteStream.size());
   response.addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
}
}
```

Comment: Not clear . Constructing url & response are different things, isn't it?

Comment: Yup i understand that. but i want to know if there is a way in which i can intervene/specify the accepted response that will be received after constructing a URL so that when someone hits the URL my specified values will be used in the response headers..

Comment: If you have access to the response, you can use the addHeader method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Is the URL being hitted on your application server or on external servers?

Comment: @MartinWickham if the URL hits to an external server, you can't do that.

Comment: My application server.

Comment: Use a [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) with a pattern that match your URLs and add the headers in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: You have access to the server which transmits the video.

The code which transmits the video to your client (IOS device) should set the response headers before sending the response(video content). If it is a Java program which serves the request for the video, you can set the appropriate header in the Servlet API (See Martin's link).

Hope that helps.